Does the support of a smooth compactly supported function have a smooth boundary?
Let $U$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ an infinitely differentiable function with compact support. My question is whether $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ has a smooth boundary and if so, why?
For context: My aim is to show that $\int_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot f=0$ using Gauss.
Edit: I need to show that $\int_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot (fp)=0$ for $p:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable. As was pointed out in the comments, $\int_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot f=0$ is trivial.
My idea so far is as follows:
We have $\int_{\Omega}\nabla\cdot (fp)=\int_{\operatorname{supp}(f)}\nabla\cdot (fp)$ so I wanted to show that the boundary of $\operatorname{supp}(f)$ is smooth, which is not true.
My other idea is to find a set $\Omega'$ with a smooth boundary such that $\operatorname{supp}(f)\subset\Omega'\subset\Omega$ and then apply Gauss.

Let $f$ be smooth on $\mathbb R$ of support $[0,1]$ then $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)f(y)$ has support equal to the square.

More generally, every closed set is the zero set of a smooth function, see e.g. this answer in too general a setting. But I'm sure you will find easy references by typing the right keywords.

@AlexanderWolfram for your integration by parts, just notice that your integral also runs over any (smooth) open set which contains the support of $f$, a very large ball for instance.

Thank you for pointing that out. I edited my question, which now contains what my actual aim is.

Why can't you extend $fp$ by $0$ and integrate by parts on some large ball?

Regarding the claim that every closed set is the zero-set of a smooth function, the answers to this question on MSE (or alternatively this one) may be simpler to understand than the very general answer linked to in the comment of @PierrePC.

@Keba I did that just now and I think it worked but I somehow feel like a part in my proof is not rigorous enough. I will leave it how it is though now. Thanks.

If you have a compact subset $K$ of some open set $\Omega$ I understand your question as : can I find a smooth set $K'$ such that $K\subset K' \subset\Omega$ ?
The natural strategy would be to use the distance function $\mathrm{d}_K: x\mapsto \mathrm{d}(x,K)$ and consider the closed set $K' := \mathrm{d}_K^{-1}([0,\delta])$ which, for $\delta$ small enough, satisfies both inclusions.
However, there's no reason for $\mathrm{d}_K$ to be smooth. That's not a real problem : you can replace it by a smooth approximation (or use the regular distance of Stein given in Theorem 2 of his book). Also, you have to be careful when you choose $\delta$ to avoid the unlucky case in which it's a critical point, but this is easily handled by Sard's theorem. Then, Proposition 5.47 of Lee's book allows to conclude.
